# what's the lightest lib able to load FBX in Android?

Tags: android, autodesk, fbx, assimp

what's the lightest lib able to load FBX in Android?
autodesk official fbxsdk still not support Android.
assimp workd in Android, but is there any other lib smaller than it?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assimp or the official SDK are not the best choise for you I guess. Just for getting fbx loader you can try [ufbx](https://github.com/ufbx/ufbx) . It is easy to integrate. Another option would be to use assimp for importing the data into you own format on android and use your own loader.